# an issue about extract source code of an apk

Tags: android, duplicates, apk, apktool, dex2jar

Hello I lost my last backup of my project and there is just installed the app on my phone so I need to rescue my codes.

I searched dex2jar,apktools etc but they did not work.
In my apk there is 6 dex class so I  can not reach my code

Comment: Simply say, You can't. By using any method you can't get your source code as you have in android studio. At max you can get class files which you can view

Comment: Why in a world did you not use git and hosted your code on Githuib.com or similar version control hosting provider? Please put your code under Version Control

Comment: I forgot you're right :/ i will never make this mistake again however i got my xml files

Answer (score 0):

You can extract your code from http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk this link

> **Note:** It can give you all your java classes and resources, but you
>   have to work on it for some missing constraints. Please do not make
>   misuse of that....

But its better to have something than nothing.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work.its still six classes.dex and whent i use dex2jar output is unnecessary things like com>android>tools>ir and other things not my classes. :/

Comment: After uploading apk, you find various folder open com -> packagename -> here your java files and for xmls res - > layout